# Error with hosting a jsp file in Apache Tomcat 7.0.8

Tags: apache-2.2, jsp, tomcat

I have little experience with hosting and administering jsp sites in Apache Tomcat 7.0.8. Today I tried to host a site Apache Tomcat 7.0.8 but its giving me error like following:

Bad Gateway

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.

Additionally, a 502 Bad Gateway error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How do I fix such issues.

Comment: look at the logs and see if there is any error, and add that to the question

Comment: Hi Jose thanks for the reply, I could resolve this issue now by restarting the server and properly starting Apache and Tomcat. I have a small question again though. How do make my site, www.mywebsite.com, read from webapps/mywebsite.war; It is currently reading from ROOT folder. Where do I need to make the changes in settings?

Comment: You are supposed to create separate posts for separate questions. But this your question is already answered many times on stackoverflow, just do a search and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Hi Mindas thanks for your suggestion. I did search for that question all over but I couldn't find one specific to my issue. I'd appreciate if you could pass me any guidance or any helpful URL. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your site www.mywebsite.com read from webapps/mywebsite.war, it depends what do you use for reverse proxy:

- Apache Web Server + mod_rewrite
- Apache Web Server + mod_proxy
- Apache Web Server + mod_jk

You can find in their manuals how to do that. Tell me what you are using, may be I can give some more information.